# Meta viewport doesn't work at all with my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I have this site: https://checkvinhistory.co/
The problem is that isn't mobile compatible.
I tried the Meta viewport html code and a few codes in css but nothing works...
Until now the Meta viewport html code was enough and worked great with all my other websites...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: show you relevant code please

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an example of a good question. Please see here: [How to ask a good question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)

Comment: The relevant tag is neither in this question or the website's source code. Please provide it alongside your question.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "Didn't work" is not a clear problem statement, and your question should include a [mcve] *in the question itself*.

Comment: I've added the html and css code,something else needed?

Comment: If I put this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
this doesn't solve the problem'
any else idea?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{margin:0px; padding:0px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}





@font-face {
    font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO;
    src: url('font/av.otf');
 font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO;
    src: url('font/fb.otf');
 font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO;
    src: url('font/me.ttf');
 font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO;
    src: url('font/jk.otf');
}




#contaner{width:100%; margin:0 auto;}

#header{width:1100px; margin:0 auto;}

#logo{width:307px; float:left;}

#header-left{float:right; margin:10px;}

#header-left h1{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:800; color:#008bc0; font-style:italic; margin:0px; padding:0px; font-size:30px; line-height:25px;}

#header-left h2{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:800; color:#363636; font-style:italic; margin:0px; padding:0px; font-size:20px;}

#header-right{width:220px; float:right; margin:10px 0;}

#header-right1{width:110px; float:left; border-right:#999999 solid 1px;}

.view{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#000000; margin:0px; padding:0px; text-align:center;}
.view a{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#000000; margin:0px; padding:0px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none;}
.view a:hover{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#008bc0; margin:0px; padding:0px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none;}


#banner-part,
#banner-part2 {width:100%; margin:0 auto; border-top:#014e6b solid 3px; background:url(images/car-bg.png) no-repeat; background-position:center; background-position:top; width:100%; position:relative;}

#banner-part2 { margin-bottom: 10px; }



#fome{width:455px; float:left; margin-left:150px; background:url(images/yello.png) no-repeat; height:405px; margin-top:12px; }

#fome-in{width:100%; float:left; margin-top:100px;}
#fome-in h1{font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO; font-weight:700; color:#003e56; font-style: normal; margin:0px; padding:5px 17px; font-size:27px;}
#fome-in p{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:700; color:#000; font-style: normal; margin:0px; padding:5px 20px; font-size:14px;}

.sb{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:30px; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#014e6b; padding:6px 15px; margin-left:300px; margin-top:10px; border-radius:5px; border:none; font-weight:bold;}



.input{width:90%; height:50px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border: #999999 solid 1px; padding:0 5%; border-radius:5px;}
.inbox{width:100%; height:50px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border: #999999 solid 1px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; color:#333333; background:none; border:none; padding:0 ;}

/*vavigation-bar-start*/

#navu{
 width:710px;
 float:right;
 top: 0px; background:url(images/nav.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


#nav-main{
width:660px;
float:right; margin-left:50px; margin-top:0px; padding:0px; height:43px;


}



.nav ul{ padding:0px; margin:0px; list-style: none;}

.nav li{
 display:inline;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#FFFFFF;  padding:0px 15px;
}

#vin_table td,
#vin_table tr {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.nav a{
font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO; font-weight:400;
color:#fff;

text-decoration:none;
font-size:16px;
line-height:40px;
text-align:center; padding:0 0px;

}

.nav a:hover{  
font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO; font-weight:400;
color: #FFCC00;

text-decoration:none;
font-size:16px; 
text-align:left;
 
}

#text-part{width:1000px; margin:0 auto; }

#left{width:650px; float:left;}
#lright{width:300px; float:right;}

#cccy{width:1345px; margin:0 auto; margin-bottom: 30px;}

#left h1{font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO; font-weight:800; font-size:27px; color:#014e6b; line-height:20px;}
#left h2{font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO; font-weight:600; font-size:22px; color:#014e6b; line-height:20px;}
#left h3{font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO; font-weight:400; font-size:17px; color:#014e6b; line-height:20px;}
#left p{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#454545; padding:0px 10px;}
#left a, #left strong { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;};


#left ul{ list-style:url(images/arrow.jpg); margin:0px; padding:0 30px;}
#left li{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000000; line-height:23px; font-size:14px;}
.bld{font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO; font-weight:400; font-size:14px; color:#454545; padding:0px;}

#gry{width:100%; margin:0 auto; background:url(images/gry.jpg) repeat-x; border-radius:5px; margin-top:20px;}
#gry h3{font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO; font-weight:400; font-size:18px; color:#014e6b; text-align:center; padding-top:20px;}

#ho{width:100%; margin:0 auto;}

#ho ul{ list-style:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#ho li{ font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO; font-weight:400; color:#202020; display: inline-block; padding:0 50px; font-size:18px;}

#futter{width:100%; margin:0 auto; border-bottom:#014e6b solid 3px; margin-top:30px; color: white;
padding: 10px; background:#014e6b; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#contact-table  td {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://checkvinhistory.co/favicon.ico">
<title>VIN History</title>
<script>
    function setDomain() {
        document.domain = 'checkvinhistory.co';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="setDomain();">
<div id="contaner">
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="307" height="64" vspace="5"></div>
    
      <div id="header-right">
      <div id="header-right1">
        <div align="center"><img src="images/car.png" width="80" height="26" vspace="10" border="0"><span class="view">Cars</span></div>
      </div>
      <div align="center"><img src="images/zep.png" width="60" height="34" vspace="5" border="0"><span class="view">Trucks</span></div>
    </div>
  <div id="header-left">
      <h2>One of The Best North American </h2>
      <h1>Vehicle History Reports</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div id="banner-part">
<div id="cccy">
  <div id="fome">
    <div id="fome-in">
      <h1>Save on vehicle history reports</h1>
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="//checkvinhistory.co/vin-check" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
        <table width="92%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="input"><label>
              <input name="vin" type="text" class="inbox" id="textfield" placeholder="VIN#:" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; color:#3a3a3a;" />
            </label></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
           
      <p> What's this?  Example: 1C2XZ934673146072</p>
        <label>
          <input name="vin" type="submit" class="sb" id="button" value="Lookup"
          onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();"/>
        </label>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="navu"><div id="nav-main"> 
        <span class="nav">
  
<ul>
<li><a href="https://checkvinhistory.co/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="https://checkvinhistory.co/vin-check">VIN Check </a></li> 
  <li><a href="https://checkvinhistory.co/vin-report">VIN Reports </a></li>
  <li><a href="https://checkvinhistory.co/vin-numbers">VIN Numbers</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://checkvinhistory.co/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</span>          
        
        
      
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div></div>
</div>
</div><div id="text-part">
  <div id="left">
  <h1>VIN check made easy in VINHistory</h1>
<p>When buying a used car, you have the right to look up a history of all known events associated with the car’s vehicle identification number (or “VIN“). Ordering a vehicle history report for a given VIN Check can help you</p>
<ul>
  <li>Avoid getting scammed: confirming ownership, mileage, and service history.</li>
  <li>Discover hidden problems: alerting you of accidents, flooding, and lemons.</li>
  <li>Estimate the car’s value: revealing rental/fleet usages and time on a dealer’s lot.</li>
</ul><p><span class="bld">VINHistory</span> is here to help with the process of finding and understanding a vehicle history report. Get started by:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Enter your VIN number in the search box</li>
  <li>Find out how to get a car’s VIN number</li>
  <li>Look up terminology in our vehicle report glossary</li>
</ul>
<div id="gry">
  <h3>See for yourself, just 3 quick and easy steps</h3>
  <div align="center"><img src="images/long.png" width="558" height="98" style=" margin:0px; padding:0px;">
  </div>
  <div id="ho">
    <ul>
      <li>1.SEARCH</li>
      <li>2.ORDER</li>
      <li>3.VIEW REPORT<br>
      </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>  </div>
<div id="lright">
    <div align="center"><a href="https://checkvinhistory.co/report?id=sample"><img src="images/sample.jpg" width="299" height="351"></a><img src="images/seal.jpg" width="248" height="108" vspace="40"></div>
 </div><div style="clear:both"></div>
</div> <!--end text-part -->
<div id="futter">
<center>Copyright © 2015 - 2018 VinHistory</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```